# How produces statistics with laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I work on a laravel application that is a bit like a quiz. You create an exercise, you add questions and each question to answers.
Until then everything is fine.
My interest is to present statistics for each exercise after schoolchildren have answered the tests.
I want to be able to display the answer percentage for each question.
Here is an example of the data structure I have:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "exercice_id": 1,
    "question": "Lorem ipsum ?",
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 1,
            "response_text": "Yes",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 1,
            "response_text": "No",
        }
    ],
    "choice": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 1,
            "response_id": 1,
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 1,
            "response_id": 1,
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 1,
            "response_id": 2,
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "exercice_id": 1,
    "question": "fake text ?",
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 2,
            "response_text": "A",
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 2,
            "response_text": "B",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 2,
            "response_text": "C",
        }
    ],
    "choice": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 2,
            "response_id": 5,
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "exercice_id": 1,
            "question_id": 2,
            "response_id": 3,
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I tried the `groupBy` method on several elements. but I have not found the formula yet.

```
return response()->json(Question::with('responses','choice')
            ->where('exercice_id',$exo->id)
            //->groupBy('choice')
            ->get(),
            200,[], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand the problem and what you're trying to achieve. Care to elaborate more detailed?

Comment: I want to display the number of times each answer has been chosen.
Example: Question 1, answer1: 10%, answer2: 50% ......

Comment: I see, but from the presented json structure I'm not very clear of your relations. But yeah, all you'd need in general is properly structured grouping. Maybe we could help if you explain a bit more detailed the tree of your relationships.